# ReadyState and status equal 1 and 0 respectively

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, apache

I had a fresh installation of Appache and PHP on my Linux machine. This is the first script I came up to test how the things are working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/html5.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>First Ajax</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var xmlhttp;

    function getNum()
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;

        xmlhttp.open("GET" , "random.php" , true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    //When Information comes back from the server
    function callback()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert("Ready")
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Nope")
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Get Random Number" onclick="getNum()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But, it seems that the line `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` evaluates to false because "Nope" is returned. The same if I replace `&&` with `||`.  If I go to localhost/random.php from my browser, it works fine. I know the exact code works on other computers. Any idea of where I am stuck?

**Edit**: Upon the comment of @Musa, I realize that the readyState equals to 1 and status to 0 meaning that the object has been created, and the send method has not been called (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . I am still lost anyway.

Comment: @Musa please read my edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`readyState` doesn't go straight to 4, it can go to other values before it reaches 4. 
Try something like this

```
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){ 
        if (xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert("Success")
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Failure")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but because my readyState is 1 and my status is 0, so your code also returns "Failure". The problem is how to make readyState equals to 1 and status equals to 200.

Comment: Not it will not, also anything other than readyState = 4 means the request is not complete.